# How to setup API routing to Supabase in Next.js with app directory?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm building a calendar web-app just as a side project and am experimenting with the app directory in Next.js. Previously, API endpoints were rather simple with the default pages/api directory. I'm unsure how to go about this now with the new directory.

I want to use a database called 'events' that I created in Supabase. To do so, should I use this directory

```
app/api/events/route.ts
```

? I am so confused how to go about this. Do I need more initialization files than that?

ChatGPT only knows the pages directory and web browsing is no help there, so here I am. To be clear, I am only using supabase for a database, not auth or user management.

Thanks for the help!

ChatGPT keeps trying to get me to create a supabaseClient.ts file in the API directory, and then have a sub 'server' directory with createEvent.ts within the API directory. But, to no avail.